# R interprator not found in in pycharm professional in fedora linux

Tags: r, pycharm, fedora

I am using fedora linux. I have installed R through

`sudo dnf install R`

[image]

The interpreter is installed in /usr/bin/R
but pycharm says this

[image]

Now when i manually try to configure the interpreter, the bin folder shows nothing.
Like this;
[image]

But actually there is R interpreter in this folder,
Look;

[image]

Guide me please how to solve this issue.